# e.StopPropagation() to ignore overlapping element

Tags: javascript

I have a mouseover event which creates a tooltip div partially on top of the div that I have my mouse over.

But if the mouse is over the tooltip , it fires my mouse out. I wanted it to ignore the newly created div so it would not fire the `mouseout`unless i mouse out of the original div. So i used `e.stopPropagation()` but it did not seem to solve the issue.

This is my code:

```
function ToolTip(e,el,data)
{
    e.stopPropagation(); //ignore other elements that overlap

    var div  = createDiv();     
        div.style.left = el.offsetLeft + 10 + 'px';
        div.style.top = el.offsetTop + 10 + 'px';
        div.className = 'ToolTip';
        div.innerHTML = 'This is a tooltip!';
        document.body.appendChild(div); 

        function removeToolTip()
        {
            el.removeEventListener('mouseout',removeToolTip,false);
            removeDiv(div); 
        }

    el.addEventListener('mouseout',removeToolTip,false);    
}

div.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(e){ToolTip(e,this,data);},false);
```

Have i misunderstood the use of `e.stopPropagation()`?

I have made a jsfiddle with the script: **http://jsfiddle.net/Lc7t7/**

Comment: *"Have i misunderstood the use of e.stopPropagation()?"*: Yes. You are trying to prevent propagation of "mouseenter" event. Moreover, there are no other uplevel "mouseenter" handlers anyway. For a detailed understanding, you may refer to [(this)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-capture) and [(this)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

Comment: So rather than propagation, what should i be doing to prevent it from occuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to prevent the tooltip from interacting with the cursor, because when it does it's *not* interacting with the element that the tooltip is for. What you need to do is make the tooltip "invisible" to the cursor. Stopping propagation doesn't help because the tooltip's parent isn't the tooltipped element, it's the `<body>` element.

Surprisingly, the answer for this isn't JavaScript, it's CSS. The [CSS `pointer-events` property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/), when set to `none`, makes an element not interact with the cursor. JavaScript should respect this, and ignore the fact that you've "moused out" of the element with the tooltip. Unfortunately, browser support is [lacking](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) in the older versions of many browsers, so keep that in mind.

Comment: damn good answer! Been trying to work this out all day! Its quite surprising it requires a CSS solution!

Comment: It also seems pretty well supported except old IE versions, and some of the features i use don't work in old IE versions anyway so its no loss.